# How to run shell script inside app bundle in macOS Catalina

Tags: python, swift, xcode, shell, macos-catalina

I am currently developing a macOS AppKit application that depends on running a shell script which is included inside the app bundle. Only when running in Catalina, the following error is produced upon running the script through a `Task`:

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main`

I was able to stop the issue from occurring by completely disabling App Sandbox in the Xcode project. The `Task`'s `currentDirectoryURL` is set to a location which the app explicitly allowed to access according to the Sandbox exceptions.

How can I run the bundled script without disabling App Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new at this myself, so I could be wrong, but I'm working on an app that is using a task for an external process, and this is what solved my permission issues.

[image: sandboxing exceptions]
[image: appropriate tab]
There are other permissions you can grant in the entitlements file. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox_entitlements

Comment: To clarify, what did you change in the Sandbox configuration in order to avoid encountering that error in Catalina?

Comment: I edited with another picture of the tab where those settings are. I changed the parts that you see are marked read/write. They were read-only. The rest is in the entitlements file that you can find in your project browser. You can add items and there's a drop-down of lots of possible exceptions.